# Certmanager: Error getting keypair for CA issuer: certificate is not a CA

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, ssl-certificate, cert-manager

I have looked in the other posts about this, without luck.

I have generated a certificate, with CA:true.
The output of `openssl x509 -noout -text -in` is:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 0 (0x0)
        Signature Algorithm: sha512WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN = identity.linkerd.cluster.local
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun 28 10:29:46 2023 GMT
            Not After : Sep 26 10:29:46 2023 GMT
        Subject: CN = identity.linkerd.cluster.local
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:d0:8e:7d:bc:cd:1a:93:69:f7:4c:a8:c4:8d:b6:
                    62:ee:6a:cd:44:7c:4b:5f:fb:02:72:38:c2:e5:d1:
                    07:70:28:bd:27:ae:f9:ec:ed:6f:3a:09:64:a1:3a:
                    44:0e:4f:b6:24:74:46:0b:38:fd:98:40:0a:31:2e:
                    c2:00:ef:8c:c3:98:1b:e6:3e:15:be:4e:86:fa:c1:
                    40:b1:70:7a:a5:9c:f6:a6:ae:2f:08:72:7d:a0:fd:
                    27:f8:08:27:d8:42:a4:1d:26:5b:5c:bf:f9:2e:16:
                    bb:a3:ea:e4:6b:7c:0f:3d:08:30:f2:bf:71:81:81:
                    33:35:d5:d0:22:3a:7c:7e:95:7f:32:b2:5d:6a:91:
                    d8:e8:dc:2b:fa:d1:ab:2a:98:1e:de:bb:76:81:41:
                    0d:c3:50:5a:da:60:d8:b8:d0:db:4c:64:1d:4f:30:
                    f5:0c:9e:98:84:5d:9b:e1:ef:40:ec:fe:a7:22:dc:
                    2c:0f:c1:91:f6:00:39:11:d2:29:ab:4c:16:f7:15:
                    81:59:82:2a:b0:60:03:08:40:b4:97:24:1e:9c:65:
                    7d:95:a7:55:9a:50:b7:fe:6c:c9:50:17:88:69:ec:
                    9f:59:32:b7:37:c9:3e:ec:3c:de:86:73:83:9c:de:
                    3b:68:e7:db:46:0a:e3:9f:31:7f:69:78:71:76:78:
                    fc:4b:fa:03:67:8d:d2:61:35:e1:5a:a4:bf:c1:b8:
                    bf:a3:90:6f:3d:78:12:33:be:3b:c5:bc:eb:fb:35:
                    3a:74:38:58:6c:a9:f2:c2:20:14:ad:e5:74:a4:a3:
                    c3:ee:e5:44:b9:c1:2e:43:37:8a:47:61:a6:8d:86:
                    91:85:90:5a:2c:32:df:3e:fc:6c:2c:68:1f:d3:1a:
                    67:ac:9b:ef:1b:0f:97:d4:99:b9:e1:72:47:fc:d0:
                    01:eb:d9:19:77:2d:8c:ab:e2:b7:9a:19:20:03:d1:
                    60:84:c5:85:c4:36:df:06:28:76:80:13:62:1d:ff:
                    59:fb:1d:cb:fa:76:10:66:56:cd:89:e4:91:41:1d:
                    66:4c:71:b4:12:3c:bd:b6:5d:fe:5c:30:7e:0a:1e:
                    88:54:38:56:48:2f:01:9f:88:b8:ef:50:3b:10:4d:
                    70:d4:dc:b4:16:6f:4d:2b:95:42:36:78:d5:9d:c4:
                    93:c9:d7:6c:a2:29:1e:0e:72:c5:c6:a0:6b:c7:d5:
                    49:b1:a9:4e:95:0c:c6:65:eb:a3:71:1e:7a:15:3c:
                    5d:35:85:56:e4:b5:28:52:49:9a:c0:8b:fd:38:79:
                    8a:d4:2c:be:43:80:9b:44:b5:09:3d:d2:59:9f:f7:
                    e3:0a:fa:b3:fd:61:73:19:33:9e:ac:d5:a8:eb:13:
                    9d:85:83
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: critical
                BE:95:DD:81:A8:9C:27:C2:B9:89:13:A7:9F:23:67:8E:1E:75:51:F0
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: critical
                BE:95:DD:81:A8:9C:27:C2:B9:89:13:A7:9F:23:67:8E:1E:75:51:F0
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:1
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: sha512WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        29:85:ad:0b:27:a6:c3:89:42:15:13:85:17:45:5c:e2:78:71:
        a0:88:ae:ec:cf:31:88:8b:35:50:15:3f:d7:0e:d7:d6:ea:e6:
        ab:e3:a3:1a:4d:2e:43:0e:e1:02:52:bf:e6:62:46:88:8f:15:
        4b:0d:32:07:19:48:5a:92:c2:6a:a4:2e:37:b5:c4:c6:ba:a7:
        b4:a9:8a:fe:38:48:b2:fa:14:c4:28:6a:c5:e2:81:5b:96:71:
        43:96:cd:6a:42:ad:fd:f0:01:db:af:2e:af:89:27:2f:cb:aa:
        a2:a4:e0:c6:b1:2b:a7:2e:e7:70:cb:af:54:3f:da:9e:ac:45:
        26:94:88:32:52:da:38:8a:ba:49:11:7e:e4:36:78:71:49:49:
        30:1f:de:9a:95:cd:96:bd:ed:3f:b5:20:4a:1a:ab:4f:cf:5c:
        72:18:47:db:81:ab:3b:cd:14:90:c8:04:08:d9:2a:74:e8:ea:
        0a:92:74:dd:8b:17:0a:f4:97:3c:a9:92:b5:bd:e9:83:f0:61:
        99:0e:76:e3:4a:67:cc:5b:ad:0e:6a:d9:7f:e7:e3:3c:d6:98:
        7c:e3:b5:11:d7:09:d1:76:90:aa:bd:35:4f:13:93:bd:49:b9:
        c7:c6:01:39:e2:93:df:2a:39:5c:43:78:c3:b2:37:32:64:42:
        f3:ea:35:6d:e9:4d:00:2d:3a:d1:5f:f9:00:7e:45:6b:73:c1:
        0a:2d:41:53:46:1b:7b:0c:1c:45:fb:ac:a1:ba:36:37:6d:b0:
        4f:a3:ef:ee:9d:6b:a5:1f:d7:53:24:a0:d2:dc:73:22:11:e4:
        0f:4d:0c:0c:d2:af:1e:71:c7:f3:f0:0f:28:38:3d:eb:20:9a:
        77:41:78:b9:c8:d8:53:52:ec:d2:43:58:9c:f0:8b:7d:d0:cb:
        0c:4e:b5:d4:23:b4:54:36:51:2d:3d:23:30:e1:bc:26:80:47:
        39:c8:1b:24:66:2e:2b:2a:ee:2f:68:24:7c:bc:66:2a:5a:70:
        6f:f4:26:6e:8e:a9:41:78:88:5f:cb:53:3d:00:69:3a:a9:53:
        0d:e0:85:05:71:ac:47:2f:f1:1e:25:2c:85:d4:d5:5b:7d:8a:
        c6:08:aa:62:74:15:74:44:7b:a3:e3:66:71:24:8b:a7:54:de:
        a3:0f:19:94:69:cf:ae:0c:df:96:65:43:a9:33:0c:ee:ee:4c:
        a9:6e:bd:df:a2:b1:0e:ec:4e:6c:ae:ba:ba:38:03:23:60:75:
        81:f6:ba:b6:0e:df:38:83:12:96:91:f3:a6:f8:15:15:f5:56:
        49:b9:0e:ac:b4:b1:bb:aa:92:7c:58:7a:2c:8a:f9:1b:a7:cc:
        9d:92:61:8c:33:8f:a2:f6
```

I have added this to my cluster with the following commands:

```
kubectl create secret tls \
    linkerd-trust-anchor \
    --cert=ca.crt \
    --key=ca.key \
    --namespace=linkerd \
    --dry-run=client --save-config -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -

kubectl apply -f certmanager.yaml
```

The content of certmanager.yaml is:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: linkerd-trust-anchor
spec:
  ca:
    secretName: linkerd-trust-anchor
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: linkerd-identity-issuer
spec:
  secretName: linkerd-identity-issuer
  duration: 48h
  renewBefore: 25h
  issuerRef:
    name: linkerd-trust-anchor
    kind: Issuer
  commonName: identity.linkerd.cluster.local
  dnsNames:
  - identity.linkerd.cluster.local
  isCA: true
  privateKey:
    algorithm: RSA
    size: 4096
  usages:
  - cert sign
  - crl sign
  - server auth
  - client auth
```

As far as I can tell, I have a proper CA certificate capable of signing new certificates, though if I do a `kubectl describe issuer linkerd-trust-anchor` I see it is failing with this event:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                    From                  Message
  ----     ------             ----                   ----                  -------
  Warning  ErrInvalidKeyPair  3m45s (x2 over 3m45s)  cert-manager-issuers  Error getting keypair for CA issuer: certificate is not a CA
```

As far as I can tell, the certificate is a CA. If I try to open the certificate in windows, windows give the message "this CA root certificate is not trusted", indicating that the certificate is indeed a CA.

Does anyone see anything obvious I am missing here?

Comment: For extensions in an X.509 certificate to be valid (and used) [**the version must be v3** (encoded as 0x2)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.1). Microsoft has a long record of not following standards correctly (if at all), so I wouldn't take anything they say as valid evidence. Plus, as voted, this is not about programming or development.